# convert content of web page to webservice

Tags: html, reporting-services, interpreter, dashboard

Our partner prepared a web page for us with reports. We have to log in everyday to view the reports.

However, our company desires to fetch information from their website automatically, and view it on an internal dashboard for managers to analyze .

We requested our partner to provide us with a web service, but they rejected this.

So, we decided to develop an application (web service) to connect to their website, and -after entering login information and authenticating- scan the HTML page and make it internally available via a web service for our branches.

**How can I do that without programming. for example the website that do it for other websites. and open that by my authentication and then request me to select the data that i want and send us as a web service...**

Comment: You need to create a webservice. Where you will read the page, Prepare a dataset etc and return to the consumer code

Comment: You're asking a *way* too broad question, which basically comes down to "how to build a screen scraping app". You should really design and build that yourself, and get back to SO if you have more *specific* problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on cURL (http://curl.haxx.se/)

And you can parse html with a html parser (google for it).

But creating a web service is a way better idea...